# Подключиться к Sharepoint из Java

Tags: java, sharepoint

Привет.
Пытаюсь подключиться к Sharepoint с помощью Java (пользуюсь Eclipse), чтобы забрать список:

```
import org.korecky.sharepoint.SPSite;
import org.korecky.sharepoint.SPWeb;
import org.korecky.sharepoint.SPVersion;
import org.korecky.sharepoint.authentication.NtlmAuthenticator;

 public class Class2 {
             public static void main(String[] args)
             throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
              MalformedURLException, ParseException {



 NtlmAuthenticator credentials = new NtlmAuthenticator("mydomain", "user", "myPassword");
 SPSite site = new SPSite(new URL("http://*********/Forms/AllPages.aspx"),credentials,null,true, SPVersion.SP2010);

 System.out.println(site);
 System.out.println("after instance1");
 SPWeb web1=site.getRootWeb();
 System.out.println(web1);
 }
}
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils
at org.korecky.sharepoint.SPSite.getRootWeb(SPSite.java:279)
at Class2.main(Class2.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 2 more
```

Не может определить SPWeb.

Если закомментить строки:

```
SPWeb web1=site.getRootWeb();
System.out.println(web1);
```

То ошибки нет, SPSite определяется, т.е. Jar подключен правильно.

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Нет библиотеки apache commons, добавьте её в classpath.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало.
Появилась новая ошибка:

Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized

Но о ней в новом вопросе, видимо :)

Answer (score 1):

Решилось добавлением библиотеки `org.appache.commons.lang3` в `classpath` проекта.